# Changing the Color of OMaths Objects in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to write a macro that will change the color of each third equation in my report to dark blue (as seen below):

[image]

I have already successfully written a some VBA to convert all equations to a professional format on open and am now needing help to change the coloring. I've tried a for loop to select the third equation, color it blue, then move onto the next one, but I haven't had any success. Previously mentioned code is below:

```
Dim j As Integer    
Dim eqRange As Range
For j = 3 To ActiveDocument.Range.OMaths.Count
Set eqRange = ActiveDocument.Range.OMaths.Item(j)
eqRange.Select
Selection.Font.ColorIndex = wdDarkBlue
j = j + 3
Next j
```

I haven't had any success with this code and when I run it line by line I can tell that it isn't selecting anything, so the colors aren't changing.

I will also include the code that I previously mentioned about converting below for reference:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Range.OMaths.Count
ActiveDocument.Range.OMaths.Item(i).BuildUp
Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument
  For i = 3 To .OMaths.Count Step 3
    .OMaths(i).Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdDarkBlue
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much for your help!